# UV mapping in viewport is different from render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv

The UV mapping in textured viewport shading mode and the rendered image is different.

I unwrapped a UV map in textured mode and then saw the result of the Cycles render.

As you can see, their UV mappings are different.
I already connected the UV output of a texture coordinate node to the vector input of an Image Texture node. The unwrapped image file is the same as the image file in the material.

How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Material Utils addon may help you: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7870/1363

Comment: Is it possible you have more than one UV map? If not, could you upload the blend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meshes in Blender can have multiple UV coordinate sets.
[image]

The one selected (blue background) is the UV map used in textured mode. The one with the small camera icon activated to the right is the default UV map used for rendering.

If your model has multiple UV maps, either click the camera icon of the map you want to use for rendering or select the map by its name as an object-attribute in the node editor:
[image]
You can find the `Attribute` node by pressing [Shift+A] and selecting Input->Attribute in the node editor.

Comment: Be careful! The rendered viewport shading won't show the changes in texture mapping until you toggle edit mode to object mode.