# Set Animation Nodes to work with animated baking

Tags: texture-baking, animation-nodes, dynamic-paint

I am not able to bake texture sequences with AN generated mesh (like *Dynamic Paint* or *Animated Render baker* add-on). It looses vital data on frame change, thus confusing baking.

I tried to use expressions to hold proper UV map for the full timeline:

```
bpy.data.meshes["Mesh"].uv_textures.active_index = 1
```

and

```
bpy.data.meshes["Mesh"].uv_textures["UVMap.001"].active_render = True
```

But this is not enough, blank *Image* doesn't associate with UV layer after frame has changed (checked it after re-entering Edit mode).

So, is there any way to make it work, or exporting meshcache is the only option for this?

Comment: Do you set UV Maps manually? Can you create a minimal working example and share its node tree?

Comment: Actually I've added a working example. If there is a better way, I'll wait for your answer, otherwise I'll accept this.

Comment: I am still not sure what the problem is, so I can't really add an answer. Make sure to add an answer if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Using this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7870/29200), I can make it work via `Script` node (*UV* input is a name of UV layer to bake to):

[image]

**Script itself:** (*Assign_img.py*)

```
import bpy

image = bpy.data.images["Untitled"]

Object.data.uv_textures[UV].active = True
Object.data.uv_textures[UV].active_render = True

for uv_face in Object.data.uv_textures[UV].data:
    uv_face.image = image
```