# Python: AttributeError: 'MeshUVLoop' object has no attribute 'image' in 'object.data.uv_layers.active.data'

Tags: python, uv

I'm trying to add an image to the UV faces. But it seems it's not working in Blender 3.4.0. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

```
image = bpy.data.images.new('MathTextureImage', 256, 256)

uv_layer = bpy.context.object.data.uv_layers.active.data

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
for uv in uv_layer.data:
    uv.image = image      # <-- HERE ERROR: AttributeError: 'MeshUVLoop' object has no attribute 'image'
```

I'm getting the error: `AttributeError: 'MeshUVLoop' object has no attribute 'image'`

`uv` only contains `['__doc__', '__module__', '__slots__', 'bl_rna', 'pin_uv', 'rna_type', 'select', 'select_edge', 'uv']`

Answer (score 4):

You cannot add images to UV maps. UV Maps are used to map images to object's surface in materials. It's unclear what you want to do, but if you wanted an image to be displayed on an object, you would have to make a material and use that image in it with UV image coordinates of your UV map and some shader.

[image]

This is how that would look with material nodes. You could use Python to create materials and material nodes and connect them.

Comment: Ah makes sense. I'm trying to set Every UV face to an Image datablock. Just found out: Before Blender 2.8 this was possible with my code snippet because it used bpy.context.object.data.uv_textures , but now it is bpy.context.object.data.uv_layers . This is why my problem occurred. Now trying to find the right python syntax to implement your solution

Comment: previously it was like this https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7870/162261

Comment: I did not know that.